# IOS Keyboard with attached entry field

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

We use the IOS UIKeyboard to enter text into a UITextField which is positioned over our OpenGL View.

Is there a simple way to attach an entry field to the top of the keyboard, so it is within the frame of the keyboard and scrolls on and off smoothly with it, rather than moving your own UITextField when the keyboard scrolls on ? Maybe some property of the text field itself ?

Thanks

Shaun

Answer (score 0):

You could put the whole view inside a `UIScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

I think `inputAccessoryView` may be what you are looking for. It´s a property of `UITextField`.

See [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619627-inputaccessoryview).

Comment: Hi. I tried this by making a white box, and it attaches fine, but then I cant then get my text to appear over the box. If it's a child of the box then when I set the inputAcccessoryView property I get a run time crash saying that the heirarchy is invalid. If its not a child then it appears under the box !  I think I just need to find a way to make my box follow the keyboard.

Comment: You can observe `UIKeyboardDidShow` Notification then. Use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` to get the Keyboard frame from the notifications userInfo. 
See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/1621602-uikeyboarddidshow#

Comment: Thanks, yes, we already used that to get the height of the keyboard incase we needed to move our text box up. What we did in the end was create a new block white view and 'attach' it to the top of the keyboard ourselves, and make the text input view a child of this new view. We initially position the new view just off the bottom of the screen and then when we got the UIKeyboardDidShow notification, we find the size of the keyboard and position it just above the keyboard. Amazingly they both scroll on together then, and it all seems to work.  I'm sure there must be a better way, but this works!